# Why an Exception is not raised in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

```
$keys = array( "layerName", "lat", "lon", "radius","CHECKBOXLIST");

$value = array();

try {

  foreach( $keys as $key ) {

    if ( isset($_GET[$key]) )
      $value[$key] = $_GET[$key];
    else
      throw new Exception($key ." parameter is not passed in GetPOI request.");
  }//foreach
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

This code written is to get values of the parameters from GET requests. If Any of these parameters is not passed in GET request, it should raise an exception. but in this case, it doesnot. What could be the problem?

Comment: @yes123: yea. it prints everything coming from GET request. but if something is not passed, it doesnot raise exception

Comment: Your code should work as expected, thus the issue is probably in the exact data set you have.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET[$key]` is probably set but has no value, so it will assign an empty string value to `$value[$key]` instead of throwing a new exception. I would rewrite your if statement to check for empty value instead.

```
if ( isset($_GET[$key]) === true && empty($_GET[$key]) === false )
{
    $value[$key] = $_GET[$key];
}
elseif ( isset($_GET[$key]) === true && empty($_GET[$key]) === true)
{
    throw new Exception($key ." parameter is not passed in GetPOI request.");
    break;
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is mostly likely what is happening. The GET variable are set but empty

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a break after throwing the exception. Like this:

```
if ( isset($_GET[$key]) )
    $value[$key] = $_GET[$key];
else{
    throw new Exception($key ." parameter is not passed in GetPOI request.");
    break;
}
```

--EDIT--

I have to quickly add that i tried running your code and raised an exception as expected.

Comment: The `break` should not make a difference. It should just stop executing, and raise the exception.

Comment: Throwing an exception automatically exits the `try` block. There is no need to `break`.

Comment: @Ikke, @Álvaro G. Vicario - i know that should be the behaviour, I only suggested adding a break after throw just incase something funny was going on. Dont think that deserves a vote down IMO